# Pandas, how to check for each date in data frame if a certain condition is met in the next 12 months period

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set like below, where for each student there is monthly attendance record, I need to check for each single StudentID and Date pair in dataframe if the student have any Absence( attendance= N) in next 12 months period. This needs to be done for a huge data where for each student there are more than 5 years data and so many students, what i do currently is i run a nested for loop which runs for each StudentID and Date pair and checks if in next 12 months there are any N or not. This takes a life to run( 4 hours+ ), i was wondering if there are any Pythonic or vectorized solution to this. Would be grateful if anyone can help.

PS.  12 month should be exact calendar 12 months and there are sometimes for some ID and Date pairs not all the 12 month data exist. For example for first record of ID 102 only next 9 months data exist, it could be zero either.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

```
StudentID   Date    Attendance
111 1-Dec-19    Y
111 1-Nov-19    N
111 1-Oct-19    Y
111 1-Sep-19    Y
111 1-Aug-19    Y
111 1-Jul-19    Y
111 1-Jun-19    Y
111 1-May-19    Y
111 1-Apr-19    Y
111 1-Mar-19    Y
111 1-Feb-19    Y
111 1-Jan-19    Y
111 1-Dec-18    Y
111 1-Nov-18    Y
111 1-Oct-18    Y
111 1-Sep-18    Y
111 1-Aug-18    N
333 1-Dec-19    Y
333 1-Nov-19    N
333 1-Oct-19    Y
333 1-Sep-19    Y
333 1-Aug-19    Y
333 1-Mar-19    Y
333 1-Feb-19    Y
333 1-Jan-19    Y
333 1-Dec-18    Y
333 1-Nov-18    Y
333 1-Oct-18    Y
333 1-Sep-18    N
333 1-Aug-18    Y
```

Desired output as below

```
StudentID   Date    AnyAbsencePrevious12Month?
111 1-Dec-19    Yes
111 1-Nov-19    No
111 1-Oct-19    No
111 1-Sep-19    No
111 1-Aug-19    Yes
111 1-Jul-19    Yes
111 1-Jun-19    Yes
111 1-May-19    Yes
111 1-Apr-19    Yes
111 1-Mar-19    Yes
111 1-Feb-19    Yes
111 1-Jan-19    Yes
111 1-Dec-18    Yes
111 1-Nov-18    Yes
111 1-Oct-18    Yes
111 1-Sep-18    Yes
111 1-Aug-18    Not applicable
333 1-Dec-19    Yes
333 1-Nov-19    No
333 1-Oct-19    No
333 1-Sep-19    No
333 1-Aug-19    Yes
333 1-Mar-19    Yes
333 1-Feb-19    Yes
333 1-Jan-19    Yes
333 1-Dec-18    Yes
333 1-Nov-18    Yes
333 1-Oct-18    Yes
333 1-Sep-18    Yes
333 1-Aug-18    Not applicable
```

Comment: post the expected output

Comment: Hi, i refined the example and added the expected output.

Comment: For example, I'm not sure why ID:111 students change August from NO to NOT, or why October, November and December of '19 change to NO.

Comment: Its not a change its the output, No means for that record in previous 12 months there is no any record == 'N', meaning there were no absence in previous 12 months. For , the other question its not "NOT"  its "Not Applicable"  which means there is no data before that date